Who are these Lanterns in Justice League: Crisis on Infinite Earths Part 3 animated movie?
In the animated movie Justice League: Crisis on Infinite Earths Part 3 some green lanterns appear and one blue lantern as recruits of Jon Stewart. Who are these lanterns and what is their origin story. Where were they mentioned before in comics or Tv series?


I can identify the blue one but he's not a Green Lantern (as per the question). The two on the left strongly remind me of characters which also appeared in the Green Lantern animated series, but they don't seem to be the same (most likely the same species though).

three of them are green lanterns and one is blue lantern but it is mentioned in the movie that they are recruited by Jon Stewart

The right most one is Aya from Green Lantern: The Animated Series. Although she is not a true Green Lantern per se, but a very advanced and sentient AI that is powered by the green energy itself.

The one in blue is Razer who is also a character from the same animated series, although he was a Red Lantern in that show, as you can see in the above image. As far as I know, he reappeared very shortly in the show Young Justice as a Blue Lantern.

I don't know the two on the left, but the left most reminds me of Zartok, also a character from the Green Lantern animated series but he wasn't a Green Lantern; he even tried to kill the protagonists who were looking for a new recruit. One-eyed with the same style of haircut. Maybe the same species?

The second one starting from the left just reminds me of one of the spider-like aliens from the Spider Guild but that's not much of a lead. Screenshot from episode 3 of the Green Lantern animated series, Razer's Edge, depicting Myglom and his guards at one of the Spider Guild prisons, and they are definitely not good guys (aka. not Green Lanterns).


The second one in the OP's picture just reminds me of the creatures from the Spider Guild but that's about it.

I believe the second lantern from the left is Xax - Four arms and insect-like eyes. Also wears a Lantern Corp uniform. Jon Stewart convinced him to rejoin the Corp.

